# How to turn score points into ammo amount?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a game where if you collect a fish you gain a point. What I want is that the point you gain will also be equivalent to how much ammo the player has to shoot these fish towards a bird that hovers in the air.

Any way I can write this or an example? Do I add a public text and drag the score text into there and start from there. I also want that for every shot there is a -1 from the score. Thank you in advance I'm new to C#!

```c#
public class Projectileshooter : MonoBehaviour 
{

    GameObject Bullet;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        Bullet = Resources.Load ("projectile") as GameObject;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("f"))
        {
            GameObject projectile = Instantiate (Bullet) as GameObject;
            projectile.transform.position = transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward * 2;
            Rigidbody rb = projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
            rb.velocity = Camera.main.transform.forward * 40;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the following script to persistent GameObject.

```c#
public class AmmoManager: MonoBehaviour 
{

    public int ammoCount;
    public Text ammoCountDisplay; // bind this to a Text object in the inspector

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        ammoCount = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
       ammoCountDisplay.text = ammoCount.ToString();
    }

    void CatchFish(int number)
    {
        ammoCount += number;
    }

    void ShotFired(int number)
    {
        ammoCount -= number;
    }
}
```

From your `Projectileshooter`, get the component in `Start()` and call `ShotFired()` whenever a shot is fired. Do the same with `CatchFish()`.

```c#
public class Projectileshooter : MonoBehaviour 
{

    GameObject Bullet;
    public GameObject persistentGameObject; // bind this object to the one that has the AmmmoManager script in the inspector
    public AmmoManager ammoManager;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        Bullet = Resources.Load ("projectile") as GameObject;
        ammoManager = persistentGameObject.GetComponent<AmmoManager>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("f"))
        {
            GameObject projectile = Instantiate (Bullet) as GameObject;
            projectile.transform.position = transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward * 2;
            Rigidbody rb = projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
            rb.velocity = Camera.main.transform.forward * 40;

            ammoManager.ShotFired(1); // deduct one ammo here
        }
    }
}
```

I've written a short [Introduction to Unity3D](https://blog.crazy.technology/post/Introduction-to-Unity3D-21c7f860) if you'd like to get to know some basics.

Comment: Your suggestion is very helpful but I noticed in the AmmoManager script under Update the line `ammoCountDisplay.text = ammoCount;` gives off an error. I even used `using UnityEngine.UI;` but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: What's the error? Have u assigned it in the inspector?

Comment: The error is " Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to `string'. So it won't let me assign it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Oops. Updated code with `ToString()`. Googling your error is usually a good place to start learning to debug code :)

Comment: If I've answered your question, please mark as answered. Thanks!

Comment: I realized you didn't need `ammoManager = persistentGameObject.GetComponent<AmmoManager> ();` under the `void Start ` . Else it would start the game with nothing in the inspector.